# C# проверка на null поля в в LINQ запросе

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Имеется следующий код:

```
IQueryable<User> users = from c in db.UserSet
                                               where c.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value &&
                                                     c.FirstName == textBox2.Text &&
                                                     c.LastName == textBox3.Text &&
                                                     c.Patronym == textBox4.Text &&
                                                     c.City == textBox5.Text &&
                                                     c.Country == textBox6.Text
                                               select c;
```

Помогите реализовать проверку на null в каждом поле. То есть если сейчас хотя бы одно поле будет пустым, то запрос выдаст 0 строк независимо от других условий. Как можно сделать так, чтобы пустые поля игнорировались, и запрос выполнялся по остальным условиям?

Конечно можно сделать проверку на уровне `if (textbox1.text!=null){...}` но я так понимаю это много лишнего кода.

Answer (score 4):

Привет. Думаю можно так:

```
IQueryable<User> users = from c in db.UserSet
                         where (c.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value || dateTimePicker1.Value == null) &&
                               (c.FirstName == textBox2.Text || textBox2.Text == null) &&
                               (c.LastName == textBox2.Text || textBox2.Text == null) &&
                               (c.Patronym == textBox3.Text || textBox3.Text == null) &&
                               (c.City == textBox4.Text || textBox4.Text == null) &&
                               (c.Country == textBox5.Text || textBox5.Text == null)
                         select c;
```

Comment: Попробовал этот вариант, конечный результат тот же, 0 строк если есть хотя бы одно пустое поле

Comment: попробуйте это 

    `var result = db.UserSet.Where(c => (c.Date == (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text) ? c.Date : textBox2.Text)) &&...);`

Comment: хотя в таком случае слишком много операций сравнения будет

Comment: А в dateTimePicker1.Value что лежит? Null?

Comment: Ну и в остальных полях тоже. Может там просто пусто ('') - тогда и сравнивать нужно с пустым а не с null. но работать должно

Comment: ну тоесть
 (c.FirstName == textBox2.Text || textBox2.Text == "")

Comment: или же универсально - проверка и на null и на пусто
 (c.FirstName == textBox2.Text || ((textBox2.Text ?? "") == ""))

Comment: Это если использовать ? и :

Выражению LINQ to Entities не удается распознать метод "Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.String)", поэтому его нельзя преобразовать в выражение хранилища."

В dateTimepicker всегда будет значение, его на Null проверять не нужно

Comment: Всё таки Arthur был прав, вместо null подставил "" и всё заработало. Большое спасибо))

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

Если исходить из того, что условная конструкция будет представлена в виде простой бинарной операции, для которой необходимо проверить, что значением правого операнда не является значение по умолчанию. Тогда можно воспользоваться деревьями выражений, а саму проверку вынести в отдельный метод расширения.

```
public static class EfExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIfRightIsNotDefault<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var body = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;

        if (body == null)
            return source;

        // Получаем значение правого операнда.
        var currentValue = Expression.Lambda(body.Right)
               .Compile().DynamicInvoke();

        // Получаем значение по умолчанию для типа правого операнда.
        var defaultValueForType = GetDefaultValueForType(body.Right.Type);

        // Сравниваем текущее значение со значением по умолчанию.
        var isEquals = EqualityComparer<object>.Default
          .Equals(currentValue, defaultValueForType);

        // Если текущее значение не равно значению по умолчанию.
        if (!isEquals)
        {
            // Добавляем условие в предложение where.
            source = source.Where(preducate);
            return source;
        }

        return source;
     }

     // Возвращает значение по умолчанию для конкретного типа.
     private static object GetDefaultValueForType(Type type)
     {
         var p = Expression.Convert(Expression.Default(type), typeof(object));
         return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(p).Compile()();
     }
}
```

Использование:

```
var users = db.UserSet
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value)
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.FirstName == textBox2.Text)
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.LastName == textBox3.Text)
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.Patronym == textBox4.Text)
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.City == textBox5.Text)
             .WhereIfRightIsNotDefault(p => p.Country == textBox6.Text).ToList()
```